# Wrap only words in a string in quotation marks - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Could someone please suggest a method in doing the following.

I have a string which contents look like this.

```
var string = "Argentina,2,Australia,17,Azerbaijan,1,Bangladesh,1,Belgium,2"
```

And i am wanting to only wrap the country's name in quotes. so it would look like this.

```
"Argentina",2,"Australia",17,"Azerbaijan",1,"Bangladesh",1,"Belgium",2
```

How can i go about achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! what effort have you made?

Comment: Is the end result a string (`'"Argentina",2,"Australia"...'`) or an array of strings and number pairs (`["Argentina",2,"Australia",..]`)?

Comment: The end result will need to be an array of strings and number pairs in order for it to be passed through google.visualization.arrayToDataTable

Comment: Look at the title. Does that match the goal? Update it as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

You could split and than loop over the even indexes and wrap and join back together.

Or you could do all types of regular expression patterns to pull out the pattern

```
var string = "Argentina,2,Australia,17,Azerbaijan,1,Bangladesh,1,Belgium,2"
var updatedStr = string.replace(/(\D+),(\d+),/g,'"$1",$2,');
```

But if you want an array at the end, wrapping is the wrong approach. Split the array at the comma and than convert the string to a number in the odd indexes.

```
var string = "Argentina,2,Australia,17,Azerbaijan,1,Bangladesh,1,Belgium,2";
var parts = string.split(",");
for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i+=2) {
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i],10);
}
```

And to do the rest of your job for you....

```
var string = "Argentina,2,Australia,17,Azerbaijan,1,Bangladesh,1,Belgium,2";
var parts = string.split(",");
var out = [];
for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i+=2) {
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i],10);
    out.push([parts[i-1],parts[i]]);
}
```

Comment: This is almost there, I now just need to pair the items and wrap them in []. any ideas?

Comment: so loop by two and make the new array

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "Argentina,2,Australia,17,Azerbaijan,1,Bangladesh,1,Belgium,2"
var arr= s.split(",")
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  if (isNaN(arr[i])) arr[i] = "\"" + arr[i] + "\"";
  else arr[i] = arr[i];
}
alert(arr.join(","))
```